# number which appears more than n/3 times in an array

Tags: algorithm

I have read this problem 
[Find the most common entry in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278488/puzzle-find-the-most-common-entry-in-an-array)

and the answer from jon skeet is just mind blowing  .. :)

Now I am trying to solve this problem find an element which occurs more than n/3 times in an array  ..

I am pretty sure that we cannot apply the same method because there can be 2 such elements which will occur more than  n/3 times and that gives false alarm of the count ..so is there any way we can tweak around jon skeet's answer to work for this ..?

Or is there any solution that will run in linear time ?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761106/determine-if-more-than-half-of-the-array-repeats-in-a-distinct-array). Read Jan's answer - "it should be possible to adapt to a threshold of 33%".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Jan Dvorak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761366/13005) is probably best:

- Start with two empty candidate slots and two counters set to 0.
- for each item:

  - if it is equal to either candidate, increment the corresponding count
  - else if there is an empty slot (i.e. a slot with count 0), put it in that slot and set the count to 1
  - else reduce both counters by 1

At the end, make a second pass over the array to check whether the candidates really do have the required count. This isn't allowed by the question you link to but I don't see how to avoid it for this modified version. If there is a value that occurs more than n/3 times then it will be in a slot, but you don't know which one it is.

If this modified version of the question guaranteed that there were *two* values with more than `n/3` elements (in general, `k-1` values with more than `n/k`) then we wouldn't need the second pass. But when the original question has `k=2` and 1 guaranteed majority there's no way to know whether we "should" generalize it as guaranteeing 1 such element or guaranteeing `k-1`. The stronger the guarantee, the easier the problem.

Comment: yep ..I think we cant avoid ...much like boyer  moore  since we have two majority keep two possible counts ...

Comment: Second pass maybe removed via storing intersection of all removed 3 numbers (not more than 3 numbers)

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-of-size-n-finds-all-the-elements-that-appear-more-than-nk-times/

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly but could you point out why do we use 2 slots for counting?

Comment: As an example we have an array{2,1,8,2,4,2}. 2 occurs more than n/3 = 2 times. At the end of your algo the candidate slots will have 4 and 2 in them each with a count 1, is that right? So we need to just check for both 4 and 2 if they occur more than 2 times?

Comment: @Dubby: actually that example ends with one slot containing 2 with count 2, and one slot containing 4 with count 1. I'm starting to think maybe it's enough to have a guarantee that at least one element occurs with frequency greater than n/3 *and* for the two slots to have non-equal counts at the end (i.e, you don't have to do the second pass if the counts are different). But I don't have time at the moment to prove or disprove that.

Comment: Very elegant! Does anyone have a proof that this works?

Comment: @Ron In the worst case scenario the element which occurs more than n/3 times will occur in the beginning so that its freq gets decreased max times. Lets call this no. as MAXF. Now frequency of MAXF will be atleast `floor(n/3)+1` so remaining nos. are `n-floor(n/3)-1 = 2*n/3-1 + {n/3}` where `{x}` is fraction part of `x`. So  there are less than `2n/3` no.  . Among them more of them contribute to increasing one counter, and less of them contribute to decreasing both the counters because the first of these nos. increases one of the counters. So we can say the MAXF counter will always be nonzero

Answer (score 5):

Using Boyer-Moore Majority Vote Algorithm, we get:

```
vector<int> majorityElement(vector<int>& nums) {
    int cnt1=0, cnt2=0;
    int a,b;
    for(int n: A){
      if (n == a) cnt1++;
      else if (n == b) cnt2++;
      else if (cnt1 == 0){
        cnt1++;
        a = n;
      }
      else if (cnt2 == 0){
        cnt2++;
        b = n;
      }
      else{
        cnt1--;
        cnt2--;
      }
    }
    cnt1=cnt2=0;
    for(int n: nums){
        if (n==a) cnt1++;
        else if (n==b) cnt2++;
    }
    vector<int> result;
    if (cnt1 > nums.size()/3) result.push_back(a);
    if (cnt2 > nums.size()/3) result.push_back(b);
    return result;
}
```

Updated, correction from @Vipul Jain

Comment: The condition inside the for loop are in wrong order. Should be like this:
https://pastebin.com/VLebYHRD

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the number in the n/3 place and 2n/3.

```
n1=Selection(array[],n/3);
n2=Selection(array[],n2/3);
coun1=0;
coun2=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(array[i]==n1)
      count1++;
    if(array[i]==n2)
      count2++;
}
if(count1>n)
   print(n1);
else if(count2>n)
   print(n2);
else
   print("no found!");
```

Comment: Note that this requires more than one pass over the data, so it doesn't satisfy the requirements of the original question. But neither does mine.

Comment: for(i=0;i>n;i++), maybe shoulbe i<n ?

Comment: @Steve Jessop linear time=O(N)===>Selection=O(N)   2*Selection + overThe Array=2*O(N)+O(N)=O(N)!!!!

Comment: @OneManCrew: I agree, it runs in linear time. I was just pointing out that the original question called for a single-pass algorithm. The questioner has not made clear what "solve this problem" really means, is all, since the original problem called for single-pass but then this question further asks whether there is *any* linear time solution.

Comment: You may use 1 counter and use ++ and -- and compare with zero =)

Comment: @OneManCrew could you point out the specific algorithm that could be used here

Answer (score 3):

I use the following Python solution to discuss the correctness of the algorithm:

```python
class Solution:
    """
    @param: nums: a list of integers
    @return: The majority number that occurs more than 1/3
    """
    def majorityNumber(self, nums):
        if nums is None:
            return None
        if len(nums) == 0:
            return None

        num1 = None
        num2 = None
        count1 = 0
        count2 = 0

        # Loop 1
        for i, val in enumerate(nums):
            if count1 == 0:
                num1 = val
                count1 = 1
            elif val == num1:
                count1 += 1
            elif count2 == 0:
                num2 = val
                count2 = 1
            elif val == num2:
                count2 += 1
            else:
                count1 -= 1
                count2 -= 1


        count1 = 0
        count2 = 0

        for val in nums:
            if val == num1:
                count1 += 1
            elif val == num2:
                count2 += 1

        if count1 > count2:
            return num1

        return num2
```

First, we need to prove claim A:

**Claim A**: Consider a list `C` which contains a majority number `m` which occurs more `floor(n/3)` times. After 3 different numbers are removed from `C`, we have `C'`. `m` is the majority number of `C'`.

**Proof**: Use `R` to denote `m`'s occurrence count in `C`. We have `R > floor(n/3)`. `R > floor(n/3)` => `R - 1 > floor(n/3) - 1` => `R - 1 > floor((n-3)/3)`. Use `R'` to denote `m`'s occurrence count in `C'`. And use `n'` to denote the length of `C'`. Since 3 different numbers are removed, we have `R' >= R - 1`. And `n'=n-3` is obvious. We can have `R' > floor(n'/3)` from `R - 1 > floor((n-3)/3)`. So `m` is the majority number of `C'`.

Now let's prove the correctness of the `loop 1`. Define `L` as `count1 * [num1] + count2 * [num2] + nums[i:]`. Use `m` to denote the majority number.

**Invariant**

The majority number `m` is in `L`.

**Initialization**

At the start of the first itearation, `L` is `nums[0:]`. So the invariant is trivially true.

**Maintenance**

1. `if count1 == 0` branch: Before the iteration, `L` is `count2 * [num2] + nums[i:]`. After the iteration, `L` is `1 * [nums[i]] + count2 * [num2] + nums[i+1:]`. In other words, `L` is not changed. So the invariant is maintained.
2. `if val == num1` branch: Before the iteration, `L` is `count1 * [nums[i]] + count2 * [num2] + nums[i:]`. After the iteration, `L` is  `(count1+1) * [num[i]] + count2 * [num2] + nums[i+1:]`. In other words, `L` is not changed. So the invariant is maintained.
3. `f count2 == 0` branch: Similar to condition 1.
4. `elif val == num2` branch: Similar to condition 2.
5. `else` branch: `nums[i]`, `num1` and `num2` are different to each other in this case. After the iteration, `L` is `(count1-1) * [num1] + (count2-1) * [num2] + nums[i+1:]`. In other words, three different numbers are moved from `count1 * [num1] + count2 * [num2] + nums[i:]`. From claim A, we know `m` is the majority number of `L`.So the invariant is maintained.

**Termination**

When the loop terminates, `nums[n:]` is empty. `L` is `count1 * [num1] + count2 * [num2]`.

So when the loop terminates, the majority number is either `num1` or `num2`.

Answer (score 2):

At line number five, the `if` statement should have one more check:

```
if(n!=b && (cnt1 == 0 || n == a))
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are n elements in the array , and suppose in the worst case only 1 element is repeated n/3 times , then the probability of choosing one number that is not the one which is repeated n/3 times will be (2n/3)/n that is 1/3 , so if we randomly choose N elements from the array of size ‘n’, then the probability that we end up choosing the n/3 times repeated number will be atleast 1-(2/3)^N . If we eqaute this to say 99.99 percent probability of getting success, we will get N=23 for any value of “n”.

Therefore just choose 23 numbers randomly from the list and count their occurrences , if we get count greater than n/3 , we will return that number and if we didn’t get any solution after checking for 23 numbers randomly , return -1;

The algorithm is essentially O(n) as the value 23 doesn’t depend on n(size of list) , so we have to just traverse array 23 times at worst case of algo.

Accepted Code on interviewbit(C++):

```
  int n=A.size();
  int ans,flag=0;
  for(int i=0;i<23;i++)
  {

int index=rand()%n;
int elem=A[index];
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(A[i]==elem)
    count++;
}

if(count>n/3)
{
    flag=1;
    ans=elem;
}

if(flag==1)
break;
}

if(flag==1)
 return ans;
else return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main idea here is that, both the counters are only working over (2n/3)-1 elements of the array if 2 elements occuring over n/3 times exist.

```
if(cnt1 == 0 && arr[i] != el2)
    {
        cnt1++;
        el1 = arr[i];
    }
    else if(cnt2 == 0 && arr[i] != el1)
    {
        cnt2++;
        el2 = arr[i];
    }
```

Think about this example : 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3, here var cnt1 starts scanning from 1 and cnt2 starts scanning after the iterator reaches 2 and even after that cnt2 goes on to scan 3 so basically one counter scanned  3 elements and other scanned  5 elements.In the 5 elements scanned by the cnt2 variable, we can think it as basic implementation of Moore's algorithm and we got 3 as answer.

One counter can only scan 2n/3-1(2n-3 for simplicity) elements and by basic math,we get,
(2n/3)*(1/2) = (n/3)

This mathematical result basically tells us that if we find the element which occurs more than half times in (2n-3) elements, we will find the element which occurs more than n/3 times in the overall array.

Comment: could you provide a link to an algorithm where we can try this, please? How would we verify the actual counts in the full array to confirm they appear more than n/3 times?

Comment: This approach is based upon Moore's voting algorithm. We can simply loop over the entire array and use a counter variable to count the number of time el1 or el2 appears.
Links - [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyer-moore-majority-voting-algorithm-for-searching-elements-having-more-than-k-occurrences/)
[link](https://takeuforward.org/data-structure/majority-elementsn-3-times-find-the-elements-that-appears-more-than-n-3-times-in-the-array/)

 .Also, note that if the element obtained using Moore's voting algorithm is not appearing over n/3 times then no such number exists in the array